# ImageView.setImageResource warning for NullPointerException

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to set an Image for CollapsingToolbarLayout, and I get an warning for NullPointerException when calling ImageView.setImageResource. I have now idea why it is there.

My onCreate in Activity (Warning is in the If/Else if part)

```
public class LevelActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewClickListener {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LevelAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ImageView imageView;

static final String STATE_LEVEL = "currentLevel";

private int level;
private int[] picResource;
ArrayList<Bitmap> mDataPicture;
ArrayList<String> mDataText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level_activity);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        level = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        level = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Level");
    }

    mDataPicture = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    mDataPicture = loadData(level);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic_main);
    if (level == 1) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_office);
    } else if (level == 2) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_lvl1_1);
    }

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
    // Use a grid layout manager
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    // Specify an adapter
    adapter = new LevelAdapter(mDataPicture, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And my XML Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/level_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pic_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/level_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: try to call imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.pic_office); instead of imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_office);

Comment: Ok, it works like this imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pic_office)); Any idea why there was the warning? Thank you very much for the solution!

Comment: It is just a warning ryt? You are not getting an error. This is probably not because of imageview

Comment: No, no error, it is just a warning. I can run the app no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 if (level == 1) {
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic_office);
} else if (level == 2) {
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.test);
} else {
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic_lvl1_1);
}
```

Comment: This produces the same warning.

Comment: @JakaK There is some problem i have implemented same code and didn't get any warning in android studio. This warning never affect your app performance.